# automatic installation of IPython notebook keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, customization, jupyter-notebook

The [IPython notebook documentation](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/2.x/examples/Notebook/User%20Interface.ipynb) describes code that can be executed in a notebook to install a new keyboard shortcut. For instance:

```
%%javascript

IPython.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.add_shortcut('r', function (event) {
    IPython.notebook.execute_cell();
    return false;
});
```

I want to define a shortcut so that it is automatically installed every time I open a notebook. Where should I put it? (I already tried `profile_default/ipython_notebook_config.py` and `profile_default/startup/`. The first throws an exception; the second has no effect.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to the answer. First, the easy part: where to put the shortcut definition. It goes in `profile_default/static/custom/custom.js`. The second part, which was a little harder, was how to get it to execute every time a new notebook is opened. For this, the shortcut definition needs to be enclosed in:

```
$([IPython.events]).on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function(){
    <definition>
});
```

...and that does it!